# Path system variable for JDK 8

Tags: java, variables

I've just installed java 8 and Android SDK tools keep giving me an error that SDK can't be found so I was wonderng if my path is wrong C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.6.0_18\bin ?

Comment: Well, presumably your JDK isn't installed to `jdk1.6.0_18`. That is unless you have done something very odd.

Comment: Check whether the installation is there. Also sometimes when you change the path, it does not get reflected immediately. Try restarting your computer.

Comment: should it be jdk1.8.0_18? becasue I isntalled JDK 8

Comment: Did you try restarting?  Also check your java version from cmd

Comment: I think my path should be C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_05\ but it still doesn't recognize it.

Answer (score 0):

Press Back when you get the notification and then Next. This time it will find the JDK

Comment: It didnt find it unfortunately